# ¿Como puedo limitar los resultados en una tabla?

Tags: php

Necesito limitar los resultados en una tabla. Son solo nombres los que muestro en la tabla pero quiero que me aparezcan 10 resultados por pagina. Se que puedo hacer una paginación de resultados, pero me gustaria saber si a traves de la consulta los puedo limitar o que haya otra manera de hacerlo que no sea la paginación. Solo quiero mostrar 10 no necesito ver los otros resultados paginados porque tengo un buscador que al escribir me arroja los resultado.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos al menos qué consulta SQL es la que estás usando o cómo almacenas/obtienes los resultados de la consulta para poder indicarte cómo mejorar el código? En caso contrario es muy amplia la respuesta.

Comment: Una consulta normal Oscar. Pero creo que con el LIMIT de SQL me funcionara. Gracias

Comment: Alejo, entonces puedo mejorar la respuesta porque `LIMIT 10` sólo funciona para los 10 primeros resultados, no para el resto de páginas, y creo que deseas hacer paginación. Si deseas una respuesta más completa (y que te reabra la pregunta) edítala agregando la consulta que usas, qué variables GET usas para elegir el número de página (y opcionalmente también otra variable GET para el número de elementos por página si lo deseas) y si usas PDO o mysqli. Te expondré una solución más completa.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Si uso PDO y tengo una paginacion hecha, pero no queria usar paginación, utilizare el LIMIT de SQL porque no importa que muestre los primeros 10 ya que tengo un input que me busca por el nombre del alumno esto lo hago mediante AJAX hago esa petición a la base de datos y me muestra el alumno que estoy buscando.

Comment: Lo que no es Oscar es que si muestro los primeros 10 resultados, cuando vaya a escribir en el input el nombre a buscar este busque nada mas en los 10 que esta mostrando! Tengo esa duda

Comment: No entiendo esa última duda. Si usas jquery o xhr puedes enviar lo que has tecleado para que busque sólo lo que contenga esos caracteres. Edita la pregunta y agrega el javascript para ayudarte o crea una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Exacto Oscar eso es lo que tengo hecho. La duda es que como estoy limitando la consulta a los primeros 10 registros, no se si haya problema cuando realice la busqueda, osea que vaya a buscar solo en los 10 primeros registros que estoy mostrando con el LIMIT 10.

Comment: Depende de qué estés usando. ¿Es angular.Js? Entonces la respuesta es que sí. Por eso te recomiendo que des más detalles para poder darte una buena respuesta.

Comment: No, solo hago la petición con AJAX, y muestro los datos en una tabla normal! Creo que no debería haber problema al buscar así me aparezcan los primeros 10 registros nada mas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estoy seguro de la base de datos que usas, pero al generar la consulta a la base puedes agregarle el limite:

MySQL

SELECT firstname, lastname, email
FROM users
LIMIT 10